# An easy riddle for you

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Have fun with this one! I hope it's a pleasant rest stop for your mind :)

> Listen for this word!
>   For it begins with a high
>   And ends right on cue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume the answer is:

> [Haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku)

Since:

> The word has a "high" sound at the start, and a "cue" at the end.
>
>  The riddle itself is presented in Haiku form (a total of 17 syllables with phrases of 5, 7, 5 syllables for each line).

Comment: Spot on! Hope you enjoyed.

Comment: Do people really pronounce the second syllable as "kyoo"?  I have only ever heard (and said) "koo".

Comment: @Hellion I don't think anybody does, but it sounds similar enough for it to work.

Comment: @Hellion For you, it can end with a coup.

Comment: @Hellion depends where youre from. I live in britain and we pronouce it kyoo not koo...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I live in south-east England, I've never heard that pronunciation

Comment: @Ambo100 huh. I've never heard it pronounced koo before :P (I live in south england)